# can you override the String constructor in js

Tags: javascript, dom, constructor, overriding

I am Creating a JS library called EasyDOM and I have a function called `$EasyDOM.toEasyDOM.String()`

I just wanted to know if this is valid (in all major browsers). The context of the function is below, if needed:

```js
var $EasyDom = {        //there are more methods on $EasyDOM and toEasyDOM
    toEasyDOM: {        //but they are not relevant so I didn't post them
        String(e) {     //however it might be relevant to know it will
            e = e + ''; //be called like this.String(e)
            try{document.querySelector(e + '')}
            catch(e) {return this.Array([])}
            const $DOMFunctions = {/*a bunch of methods*/};
            return $DOMFunctions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think you are overriding the `String` constructor here. you certainly can define your own scoped function called `String`

Comment: OK, so now I have my own method called string in toEasyDOM. when it is called though, will it throw an error or return a blank string or something like that?

Comment: OK, so now I have my own method called string in toEasyDOM. when it is called though, will it throw an error or return a blank string or something like that?

Comment: It will not throw an exception since you are catching it and it will not return a blank strings since it'll either return `$DOMFunctions` or the thing `this.Array([])` returns. And yes, the code itself is valid as in it'll parse and run.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help, I just wanted to confirm whether it is valid or not because I am still a beginner